# IOS: I am using AVPlayer for Playing Video how can i make pause button

Tags: objective-c, avplayer

While playing video using AVPlayer if I click Pause Button the video have to stop. Then, if I click play button the video should resume. Does anyone have tips on how to get started?

Answer (score 1):

In ViewController which contain your AVPlaer you should create property playValue

```
@interface YourViewController: UIViewController 

    @property (nonotomic, assign) BOOL playValue;

@end
```

Then you should add UIButton on view with selector -playPauseSelector

```
-(void)playPauseSelector:(UIButton *)button
{
   if (_playValue) { 
//set pause image for button
[_player pause];
}
else {
//set play image for button
[_player play];
}
_playValue = !_playValue;
}
```

Comment: How to get _PlayValue ??

Comment: You should create @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL playValue;

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit?

Comment: Good answer VladZ, and +1 for a code example. The OP seems a bit new to programming, mind editing your post to show how to create the _playValue BOOL?

Comment: Its not working  - (IBAction)playOrPause:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Played button");

    if (_playValue) {
        [avPlayer pause];
        NSLog(@"pause");
    }
    else{
        [avPlayer play];
    }
    _playValue = !_playValue;
}

Comment: I added some changes. I hope it will be clear.